# calculate time differences between consecutive rows using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv file that has a date column. I want to calculate time differences between consecutive rows using pandas. how can I calculate time differences in seconds and write it in a new column? I already checked similar questions but their date format was different.this is top five rows of  my data

```
2017-02-01T00:00:01
2017-02-01T00:00:01
2017-02-01T00:00:06
2017-02-01T00:00:07
2017-02-01T00:00:10
```

I tried

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Output1.csv')
df['Time_diff'] = df['BaseDateTime'].diff()
print(df)
```

but got this error

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0dc1df27a3d2> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 df=pd.read_csv('Output1.csv')
----> 3 df['Time_diff'] = df['BaseDateTime'].diff()
      4 print(df)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in diff(self, periods)
   2356         dtype: float64
   2357         """
-> 2358         result = algorithms.diff(self.array, periods)
   2359         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   2360 

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in diff(arr, n, axis, stacklevel)
   1924             out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] ^ arr[lag_indexer]
   1925         else:
-> 1926             out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
   1927 
   1928     if is_timedelta:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, cool. Now, don't post the image of data, post data we can copy and paste into python ourselves, please. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: The `TypeError`is telling you that the date is stored as a `str` in the dataframe, and not interpreted as a date as you are hoping. You need to tell pandas that the values in column `BaseDateTime` are dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = io.StringIO('''
dates,nums
2017-02-01T00:00:01,1
2017-02-01T00:00:01,2
2017-02-01T00:00:06,3
2017-02-01T00:00:07,4
2017-02-01T00:00:10,5
''')

df = pd.read_csv(s)
```

**Currently the frame looks like this:**

`nums` is nothing and just there to be a secondary column of "something".

```
                 dates  nums
0  2017-02-01T00:00:01     1
1  2017-02-01T00:00:01     2
2  2017-02-01T00:00:06     3
3  2017-02-01T00:00:07     4
4  2017-02-01T00:00:10     5
```

**Carrying on:**

```
# format as datetime
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

# shift the dates up and into a new column
df['dates_shift'] = df['dates'].shift(-1)

# work out the diff
df['time_diff'] = (df['dates_shift'] - df['dates']) / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

# remove the temp column
del df['dates_shift']

# see what you've got
print(df)

                dates  nums  time_diff
0 2017-02-01 00:00:01     1        0.0
1 2017-02-01 00:00:01     2        5.0
2 2017-02-01 00:00:06     3        1.0
3 2017-02-01 00:00:07     4        3.0
4 2017-02-01 00:00:10     5        NaN
```

To get the absolute values change this line above:

```
df['time_diff'] = (df['dates_shift'] - df['dates']) / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
```

**To:**

```
df['time_diff'] = (df['dates_shift'] - df['dates']).abs() / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: thank you very much. but what should I use as an input for s = io.StringIO('''   '''). should I read my entire csv file and use it as an input?

Comment: Yes,  the first block of the example code was just to take what you provided in the question and show its processing without saving it to a file.  You can ignore that and use `df=pd.read_csv('Output1.csv')`.  From there you can look to use the lines in my second code of code but change all the `df['dates']` to the column name required.  Looks like the column in your df is `df['BaseDateTime']`

Comment: it works !thank you. I'm gonna  plot a histogram from calculated time differences ,how can I get absolute values for differences since I have some negative values in this column. I would really appreciate for your help

Comment: @milad try `df['time_diff'] = (df['dates_shift'] - df['dates']).abs() / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)`.  Example: https://www.online-python.com/MrmX5K2xGS